# Prove that $\int_{-1}^{+1} (1-t^2)^ndt\to0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $c_n = \int_{-1}^{+1} (1-t^2)^ndt$. Prove that $\lim c_n = 0$.

(I'm well aware that a similar question has been asked before, but in all of them it was asked to find an identity for each term $c_n$. I'm only interested to show that $c_n\rightarrow 0$ and i think that it can be done without finding any identity for the sequence)

I'm trying to find sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n\leq c_n \leq b_n$ and both $\lim a_n = \lim b_n =0 $. I have already found $a_n$, since:

$$c_n = 2\int_0^{1}(1-t^2)^ndt =2\int_0^1(1+t)^n(1-t)^ndt\geq2\int_0^1(1-t)^ndt = \frac{2}{n+1}=a_n$$

and of course $\lim a_n =0$. But i'm having a hard time to find the sequence $b_n$. Any help?

Comment: The reason this integral converges to $0$ is because of the dominated convergence theorem which gives a way to infer the integral when you only have pointwise convergence of the functions as opposed to uniform convergence. If you want to only use Riemann integration techniques, any trickery you undertake to find that $c_n\rightarrow 0$ is going to likely be as tricky as finding an identity for $c_n$.

Comment: Small note: $a_n = 0$ would have been a much easier lower bound; the function is nonnegative on the interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_{-1}^{1}(1-t^2)^n\,dt\leq \int_{-1}^{1}e^{-nt^2}\,dt \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-nt^2}\,dt \stackrel{t\mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}z}{=} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-z^2}\,d = \frac{K}{\sqrt{n}}. $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first inequality comes from Taylor expansion of $e^{-nt^2}$, right? Would you mind explaining the last inequality?

Comment: @math.h: the first inequality comes from the convexity of the exponential function ($e^x\geq 1+x$ for any $x$) and the last equality is a change of variable (I am going to make it more explicit)